# Video indisponível

Tags: html, html5

Estou aprendendo HTML5 e estou com problemas em incorporar dois vídeos.
Todos eles funcionaram mas os últimos ao apertar o "play" diz que o vídeo está indisponível.

```
 <iframe width="280" height="130" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ORMcSa3CBUM" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
<iframe width="280" height="130" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rpGSFWjJhjo" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
<iframe width="280" height="130" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/k05i8bT_Pkg" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz? pois os outros links estão iguais e estão funcionando, só estes dois estão dando "Video indisponível".

Comment: Cara pelo que testei o problema é com o autoplay, quando vc tira o autoplay o video aparece normalmente... Como esse é um vídeo de musica pode ser que ele tenha alguma tag ou flag que caso vc coloque o atributo autoplay o Youtube barra o carregamento. Posso estar falando uma grande M, mas que ele carregou aqui sem o autoplay ele carregou de boa

Comment: Pode ser questão de direito autoral quando alguém sobe um vídeo para o youtube pode ser que ela escolha que o vídeo não pode ser reproduzido fora do Youtube. Não sei se é isso, só estou dizendo que as vezes vc pode procurar saber sobre isso...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Muito provavelmente seu problema está descrito aqui: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=pt-BR

**E a resposta é simples:** O proprietário do conteúdo não permitiu que o vídeo seja exibidos fora das plataformas parceira de monetização.

Repare que nas configurações avançadas de publicação do vídeo o proprietário do conteúdo pode bloquear a exibição do vídeo fora das plataformas de monetização.

> *"Use a configuração de distribuição para escolher se você quer disponibilizar seus vídeos em todas as plataformas ou apenas em plataformas de monetização. "*

Fonte: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2453875?hl=pt-BR

---

Esse é o passo a passo que o Youtube dá para bloquear a exibição

> Definir as configurações de distribuição
>   Faça login no YouTube Studio Beta.
>   No menu à esquerda, selecione Vídeos e o vídeo que você quer editar.
>   Abra a guia Avançado.
>   Na caixa Distribuição, escolha entre "Em qualquer lugar" e "Disponibilize este vídeo apenas em plataformas de monetização".
>   Selecione Salvar.

Caixa onde o proprietário define se que bloquear o vídeo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito provável que seja isso mesmo, não vejo outra explicação.

Comment: @IDW se tem essa opção e se ela funciona justamente dessa forma, é pouco provável que o vídeo não esteja carregando por algo diferente disso. O que eu reparei e achei estranho, é que mesmo quando vc desmarca o "Permitir incorporação" na pagina de configuração, lá na página do vídeo o Youtube continua mostrando a opção do botão de "Incorporar"... Ao meu ver se o dono marcou que não permite o botão deveria ficar desabilitado... A não ser que o Youtube libere a incorporação para sites parceiros... que eu não sei quais são rss. Sucesso no projeto, abs!

Comment: Provavelmente o problema não é esse, pegue o HTML de incorporação e coloque num arquivo seu e faça o teste, FUNCIONA!

Comment: @WotonSampaio então faz um teste ai com esse vídeo, é o mesmo teste que eu fiz antes de publicar essa resposta. Esse vídeo é meu, pode conferir a conta do youtube o nome de quem publicou, eu deixei ele bloqueado, mudando a Permissão de Incorporação https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BFnF_wA2fk e ao tentar colocar na minha página ele da essa mensagem. http://prntscr.com/mefzk1 . Basta vc incorporar esse vídeo e apertar o Play para testar ai tb e me fala se ele rodou no seu browser. http://prntscr.com/meg0hx

Comment: Mas o seu foi diferente, o seu realmente aparece a mensagem que ele não pode ser reproduzido, veja: https://imgur.com/wkB2H16 , no caso dele, eu consigo reproduzir todos normalmente: https://imgur.com/yABcLjE

Comment: Usei o php online pq era o que tinha de mais rápido por aqui kkkkk

Comment: Esse do print que postei foi o primeiro link de vídeo que ele postou, o que tá na minha resposta, fiz agora o msm teste com os outros 3 vídeos novos e também funcionou normalmente

Comment: @WotonSampaio o estranho eh que o YouTube continua mostrando o btn de incorporar mesmo o vídeo tendo sido bloqueado, ai quando vc incorpora na pagina ele mostra o player direitinho com a capa do vídeo e tudo, mas quando aperta Play no vídeo ai que ele da pau... Eu sou um usuário comum, não tenho conta premium nem sou parceiro do YouTube, acredito que essas pessoas possam ter mais opções de config do video para esse tipo de coisa. Da lista la que ele tinha postado antes da edição apenas os dois últimos bloquearam quando dei play, não encontrei outra explicação além dessa que respondi... []'s

Answer (score 1):

Tente isso:

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" width="280" height="130" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7FrswUVAvmA" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
```

No próprio YouTube, você clica no botão **compartilhar** e então em **incorporar**. Ele já gera o HTML para você. É só copiar e colar.

Comment: Acabei de tentar, insiste nessa mensagem de erro.

Comment: @IDW copiou do msm jeito que coloquei? Eu tinha testado seu código e tive o msm erro, mas com esse que postei foi tranquilo, só aparece que o vídeo está indisponível, é?

Comment: Copiei e falhou, também tentei copiar direto do youtube no botão que foi citado. Também deu indisponível.

Comment: @IDW é algo no link do vídeo, pq copiei o seu link e abri diretamente no navegador, deu o mesmo erro

Comment: Sim, mas tentei alguns outros links de lyrics e o erro persistia. Acabei por desistir e tentei outra música... Mesmo erro, vou tentar por outros links da mesma música e já atualizo a situação. Mas podem me dar mais dicas.

Answer (score 1):

Repare que no seu código, você começa assim:

```
<frame ...
```

O correto é `<iframe...`.

Segundo que a tag `iframe` necessita de delimitador: `<iframe ...></iframe>`.

Se você copiar **TODO** o conteúdo fornecido pelo próprio *YouTube*, você não terá problema. Veja só como é fornecido:

[image: Incorporação de vídeo - YouTube]

Agora é só você adicionar **todo o conteúdo (embed)** fornecido pelo *YouTube*:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7FrswUVAvmA" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

> Leitura recomendada: [W3CSchools - HTML iframe Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)

PS: Caso o erro persista, considere o seguinte: de uns tempos para cá, o *YouTube* tem sido bem rigoroso quanto a vídeos incorporados. É bem provável que exista alguma diretiva para prevenir fraudes e esteja bloqueando seu acesso a esse vídeo... Já pensou uma página com, sei lá, uns 50 vídeos e um BOT simulando um clique em cada um dos vídeos repentinamente?!

Teste com apenas este vídeo e tire suas conclusões. ;)

Comment: Eu testei com apenas esse e também não deu em nada. removi o autoplay e já tinha consertado a tag <iframe> e não funcionou. Testei com vários browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Opera e Brave) e até testei em outro sistema tentando encontrar alguma resposta(Nele eu testei o Edge, Firefox e Safari) e nada...